# Indicator for a uiimage in a tableView

Tags: ios, swift

so I'm perfectly able to load images into my tableview from my parse server but if it lags then the cell is just white. So what I want to do is add a custom spinning indicator to the background which will spin until the image fully loads. Here is the indicator. Its off a repository from github. The repository is "https://github.com/Tueno/MaterialLoadingIndicator" and the code for its is below. What I need help with is for someone to show me how I can implement this indicator in a cell to spin before the image loads.

Heres the code for the indicator
`class MaterialLoadingIndicator: UIView {

```
let MinStrokeLength: CGFloat = 0.05
let MaxStrokeLength: CGFloat = 0.7
let circleShapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    initShapeLayer()
}

required
init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}

func initShapeLayer() {
    circleShapeLayer.actions = ["strokeEnd" : NSNull(),
                                "strokeStart" : NSNull(),
                                "transform" : NSNull(),
                                "strokeColor" : NSNull()]
    circleShapeLayer.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
    circleShapeLayer.strokeColor     = UIColor.blue.cgColor
    circleShapeLayer.fillColor       = UIColor.clear.cgColor
    circleShapeLayer.lineWidth       = 5
    circleShapeLayer.lineCap         = kCALineCapRound
    circleShapeLayer.strokeStart     = 0
    circleShapeLayer.strokeEnd       = MinStrokeLength
    let center                       = CGPoint(x: bounds.width*0.5, y: bounds.height*0.5)
    circleShapeLayer.frame           = bounds
    circleShapeLayer.path            = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: center,
                                                    radius: center.x,
                                                    startAngle: 0,
                                                    endAngle: CGFloat(M_PI*2),
                                                    clockwise: true).cgPath
    layer.addSublayer(circleShapeLayer)
}

func startAnimating() {
    if layer.animation(forKey: "rotation") == nil {
        startColorAnimation()
        startStrokeAnimation()
        startRotatingAnimation()
    }
}

private func startColorAnimation() {
    let color      = CAKeyframeAnimation(keyPath: "strokeColor")
    color.duration = 10.0
    color.values   = [UIColor(hex: 0x4285F4, alpha: 1.0).cgColor,
                      UIColor(hex: 0xDE3E35, alpha: 1.0).cgColor,
                      UIColor(hex: 0xF7C223, alpha: 1.0).cgColor,
                      UIColor(hex: 0x1B9A59, alpha: 1.0).cgColor,
                      UIColor(hex: 0x4285F4, alpha: 1.0).cgColor]
    color.calculationMode = kCAAnimationPaced
    color.repeatCount     = Float.infinity
    circleShapeLayer.add(color, forKey: "color")
}

private func startRotatingAnimation() {
    let rotation            = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "transform.rotation.z")
    rotation.toValue        = M_PI*2
    rotation.duration       = 2.2
    rotation.isCumulative     = true
    rotation.isAdditive       = true
    rotation.repeatCount    = Float.infinity
    layer.add(rotation, forKey: "rotation")
}

private func startStrokeAnimation() {
    let easeInOutSineTimingFunc = CAMediaTimingFunction(controlPoints: 0.39, 0.575, 0.565, 1.0)
    let progress: CGFloat     = MaxStrokeLength
    let endFromValue: CGFloat = circleShapeLayer.strokeEnd
    let endToValue: CGFloat   = endFromValue + progress
    let strokeEnd                   = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "strokeEnd")
    strokeEnd.fromValue             = endFromValue
    strokeEnd.toValue               = endToValue
    strokeEnd.duration              = 0.5
    strokeEnd.fillMode              = kCAFillModeForwards
    strokeEnd.timingFunction        = easeInOutSineTimingFunc
    strokeEnd.beginTime             = 0.1
    strokeEnd.isRemovedOnCompletion   = false
    let startFromValue: CGFloat     = circleShapeLayer.strokeStart
    let startToValue: CGFloat       = fabs(endToValue - MinStrokeLength)
    let strokeStart                 = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "strokeStart")
    strokeStart.fromValue           = startFromValue
    strokeStart.toValue             = startToValue
    strokeStart.duration            = 0.4
    strokeStart.fillMode            = kCAFillModeForwards
    strokeStart.timingFunction      = easeInOutSineTimingFunc
    strokeStart.beginTime           = strokeEnd.beginTime + strokeEnd.duration + 0.2
    strokeStart.isRemovedOnCompletion = false
    let pathAnim                 = CAAnimationGroup()
    pathAnim.animations          = [strokeEnd, strokeStart]
    pathAnim.duration            = strokeStart.beginTime + strokeStart.duration
    pathAnim.fillMode            = kCAFillModeForwards
    pathAnim.isRemovedOnCompletion = false
    CATransaction.begin()
    CATransaction.setCompletionBlock {
        if self.circleShapeLayer.animation(forKey: "stroke") != nil {
            self.circleShapeLayer.transform = CATransform3DRotate(self.circleShapeLayer.transform, CGFloat(M_PI*2) * progress, 0, 0, 1)
            self.circleShapeLayer.removeAnimation(forKey: "stroke")
            self.startStrokeAnimation()
        }
    }
    circleShapeLayer.add(pathAnim, forKey: "stroke")
    CATransaction.commit()
}

func stopAnimating() {
    circleShapeLayer.removeAllAnimations()
    layer.removeAllAnimations()
    circleShapeLayer.transform = CATransform3DIdentity
    layer.transform            = CATransform3DIdentity
}

}

  extension UIColor {

convenience init(hex: UInt, alpha: CGFloat) {
    self.init(
        red: CGFloat((hex & 0xFF0000) >> 16) / 255.0,
        green: CGFloat((hex & 0x00FF00) >> 8) / 255.0,
        blue: CGFloat(hex & 0x0000FF) / 255.0,
        alpha: CGFloat(alpha)
    )
}

}`
```

And here is my code to load images from my server.

```
    let query = PFQuery(className: "Users")
    query.addDescendingOrder("createdAt")
    query.findObjectsInBackground(block: { (objects, error) -> Void in
        if error == nil {

            // clean up
            self.UserNameArray.removeAll(keepingCapacity: false)
            self.ImageArray.removeAll(keepingCapacity: false)

            // find related objects
            for object in objects! {
                self.UserNameArray.append(object.object(forKey: "User") as! String)
                self.ImageArray.append(object.object(forKey: "Image") as! PFFile)
            }

            //ADD THIS
            self.horizontalContacts.reloadData()

        } else {
            print(error!.localizedDescription)
        }
    })
```

Comment: Remove objective-c tag from your question as you are using swift code.

Answer (score 0):

```
//something like that
class ImageTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    var contentImage: UIImage?{
        didSet{
            if contentImage == nil{
                self.imageView.addSubview(MaterialLoadingIndicator)
            }else{

                self.imageView = UIImageView(image: contentImage )
            }
        }
    }


    //and in TableViewController

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellReuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! ImageTableViewCell
        if images[indexPath.row] == nil{
            cell.image = nil
        }else{
            cell.image = images[indexPath.row]
            return cell
        }
}
```

Comment: thats good but can you help me with implementing materialloadingindicator

Comment: what do you think

Comment: [link](https://www.evernote.com/l/ARIEicjI3AFF1aev0NAjIVt2ot1Md8WOSMg) [link](https://www.evernote.com/l/ARJqhrEZ0l5IMIeLUn1IkjZ1ear94QtFUsE)

Answer (score 0):

Create `MaterialLoadingIndicator` and add it as `subview` of `imageView`.

```
let indicator = MaterialLoadingIndicator(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: imageView.frame.size.width, height: imageView.frame.size.height))
indicator.center = imageView.center
imageView.addSubview(indicator)

//Start animating the loader
indicator.startAnimating()
```

And when you get image from parse server just call `indicator.stopAnimating()` and the set the image to `imageView`

Answer (score 0):

You can easily achieve this by creating a custom UIImageView class. Then you can use it whenever you want to asynchronously load images in your project.

First create a new `coca touch class` file as a subclass for `UIImageView` and give a meaningful name I suggest put `AsyncImageView` as the name.

Then Copy paste below code snippet to the created file(Here I am considering `AsyncImageView` as your created file name if not change class name correspondingly),

```
import UIKit

class AsyncImageView: UIImageView {

    /*
    // Only override draw() if you perform custom drawing.
    // An empty implementation adversely affects performance during animation.
    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        // Drawing code
    }
    */

    func downloadedFrom(url: URL, defaultImage:UIImage, contentMode mode: UIViewContentMode = .scaleAspectFit) {
        contentMode = mode

    self.image = defaultImage

    let activityView = UIActivityIndicatorView(activityIndicatorStyle: .gray)
    activityView.frame = CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: 0,y :0), size: CGSize(width: self.frame.size.width, height: self.frame.size.height))
    activityView.layer.cornerRadius = self.layer.cornerRadius
    activityView.center = self.center
    activityView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    activityView.startAnimating()
    self.superview?.addSubview(activityView)

        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
            guard
                let httpURLResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse, httpURLResponse.statusCode == 200,
                let mimeType = response?.mimeType, mimeType.hasPrefix("image"),
                let data = data, error == nil,
                let image = UIImage(data: data)
                else { return }
            DispatchQueue.main.async() { () -> Void in
                self.image = image
                activityView.stopAnimating()
                activityView.removeFromSuperview()
            }
            }.resume()
    }
func downloadedFrom(link: String, defaultImage:UIImage, contentMode mode: UIViewContentMode = .scaleAspectFit) {
        guard let url = URL(string: link) else { return }
        downloadedFrom(url: url, defaultImage:defaultImage, contentMode: mode)
    }

}
```

Thats it we had done! just save the file and use this custom class instead of UIImageView(Set class name in Identity Inspector of Xcode). After creating outlet of your imageview in your controller by dragging you can load your image asynchronously using the below code snippet

```
 @IBOutlet weak var asyncImageView: AsyncImageView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        asyncImageView.downloadedFrom(link: "https://s29.postimg.org/qqxoigjbr/Arun_Photo.png", defaultImage:UIImage(named:"noImage")!)
        // change image link to your image in parse server & default image means you can set a background image at time of indicator run
    }
```

I know as a fresher you have still doubt in these steps to get more clarity I made a sample project and you can download it from [here](https://bitbucket.org/arunjos007/swfit_asyncimageview/downloads)
https://bitbucket.org/arunjos007/swfit_asyncimageview/downloads

Comment: I have one problem though. I'm loading the images from parse. Could you take a look at my project

Comment: what do you think

Comment: Oh sure please give me the project file and specify what is the error

Comment: No problem can you give me your email so I can send it to you

Comment: please send to this email arunjos007@gmail.com

Comment: Can you give me 15 min so I can make a sample project

Comment: Because my current project is connected to my database and has all the codes in file so I have to change that

Comment: hello arunjos007, what do you think, could you diagnose the problem

Comment: Please check the mail